# How to use ExpandableListView to Add / Edit / Delete entire Row?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to add data in the expandable list view in such a way, like below,

[image]

[image]

I want to get expenses of different header like Food, Petrol and other. And want to Add / Edit / Delete Rows in every headers. Like in the image shown,

I can use List view on item click listener, but it will not be appropriate.

I want to Add Row, by default blank, edit allows on same list item layout. And I want to delete entire row, while having in the same layout.

My question is, How to implement this scenario into my App?

Is ExpandableListView is appropriate for this?

Comment: flow is either use onlong click on the list item to display delete dialogue and delete the element from the list you are setting in adapter and then reset the list by using notifydatasetchanged, yes according to my understanding expandable list view is better option you just have to manage the lists, parent and child properly

Comment: this might be of some help to you http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

i used xml file with some static Layout as default. Now as per need, i will add the different views dynamically in runtime. In short , i used ViewModel class for views to add dynamically, and DataModel class to get the data of dynamic Views,And Controller and Application classes to manage them.